# PHP MYSQL - Insert into without using column names but with autoincrement field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, auto-increment

I need to insert a long row with 32 fields into a MySQL table.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$sql="insert into tblname values (... 32 fields ...)";
```

Obviously, it works fine if the fields are in the same order as the MySQL table fields. But, my table has an auto-increment id as it's first field.

What I want is to fill in all table names but the first (id) one.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Just use `NULL` as your first value, the `autoincrement` field will still work as expected:

```
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (NULL, ... 32 Fields ... )
```

Comment: Very good.
I've also found an alternate solution as follow:

$resultx = mysql_query( "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'diretorio'");
$auto_incr_val = mysql_result($resultx, 0, 'Auto_increment');

Comment: @Paulo: you have no idea what trouble you may open yourself up to by doing that.  Use NULL - it's the way MySQL designed it to work.

Comment: It is generally fine to use 0 to trigger auto_increment unless you enable NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO mode. NULL, 0, and DEFAULT are all accepted values to trigger this. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero for more info.

Comment: Similarly, NULL can be used for other columns which have default values defined, e.g. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: this null method does not work for me. i dont know why?

Answer (score 14):

Insert `NULL` into the auto-increment field.

I recommend that unless this is a hack script, you use field names.  The rationale is that your code will **break** if you ever add a field to the table or change their order.

Instead, be explicit with field names, and it will go much better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NULL` or `0` to insert **an auto-incremented value** as shown below:

```sql
                         -- Here
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (NULL, ... 32 Fields ... )
```

```sql
                         -- Here
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (0, ... 32 Fields ... )
```

Answer (score -1):

We should omit any column values when we try without column name in insert query,

Advise if above information is wrong.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a simple shortcut that I've used:

```
$fieldlist=$vallist='';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $fieldlist.=$key.',';
 $vallist.='\''.urlencode($value).'\','; }
$fieldlist=substr($fieldlist, 0, -1);
$vallist=substr($vallist, 0, -1);
$sql='INSERT INTO customer_info ('.$fieldlist.') VALUES ('.$vallist.')';
```

Please note that this code would be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-in-adodb-and-general-website-security/12123649#12123649) and should be modified to accommodate PDO's, but I felt this simplified script would more directly answer the question with regards to the originally posted code.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Read more here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-and-adodb-library-general-php-website-security-with-examples/12123649

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev - While I agree with you and have switched over to PDO's in order to avoid SQL injection, I feel there's a benefit to answering the question as it pertains to the posted code

Comment: Yes, probably. It also worth mentioning aboug the possible problems. (I didn't downvote, just in case)