# How to insert new field in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Let assume we've database table My_table with `(id-name)`

```
CREATE TABLE `drink` (
`id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9034 ;

INSERT INTO `My_table` VALUES (1, 'my name is someone');
```

How to automate adding new fields using php or something else so that it can be `(id-new-name)`

and where new = name after we replace `spaces` to `-` using

```
$new = str_replace(' ', '-', trim($name));
```

so the table become

```
CREATE TABLE `drink` (
`id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`new` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
`name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9034 ;

INSERT INTO `My_table` VALUES (1, 'my-name-is-someone', 'my name is someone');
```

I'd like to operate it cause it has half million of lines and impossible to do it manually
so any idea!

Thanks for help.

Comment: You could do the same thing with a query, an alias, and [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do that:

1. Adding a new column to the table:

   ALTER TABLE drink ADD new varchar(100) after id;
2. Setting values for the new column using the pattern you described:

   UPDATE drink SET new = REPLACE(name, ' ', '-');

RESOURCES:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

When you insert anything i MySQL you have to specify the columns..Like this
`INSERT INTO`banans`(`id`,`sort`)  VALUES ('1','Green')`

Comment: I don't think you actually need column names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871331/php-mysql-insert-into-without-using-column-names-but-with-autoincrement-field

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the value back, and don't need to search by `new`, you can:

```
SELECT id, REPLACE(name, ' ','-') AS new, name
FROM drink
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Macovei suggested, you can generate the new name when you insert a new record by doing this:

```
INSERT INTO drink (new, name) VALUES ('the name', REPLACE('the name', ' ', '-'))
```