# Server-side validation using object oriented php; data is not inserted to the database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I was trying to insert data to the database through a form using object oriented php validation. I'm not getting any errors but data is not inserted to the database. Can someone please find me out what's wrong. A simple explanation would be highly appreciated because I'm a beginner.

These are my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Customer Registration</h1>
<form action="oovalidation.php" method="post">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="nameField"/>
<br>
<label>Mobile</label>
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobileField"/>
<br>
<button type="submit" name="submit"> Add</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function checkName(){
var text=document.getElementById("nameField").value;
if(text.length>=3){
    alert("Name is ok");
    return true;
}else{
    alert("Wrong name");
    return false;
}}

function checkMobile(){
var text=document.getElementById("mobileField").value;
if(text.length==10){
    alert("Mobile is ok");
    return true;
}else{
    alert("Wrong mobile");
    return false;
}}

function checkForm(){
var x=checkName();
var y=checkMobile();
return x&&y;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>


<?php
Class customer{
    private $name;
    private $mobile;

public function setName($name){
    $namelen=strlen($name);
    if($namelen>=3){
        $this->name=$name;
    return true;
    }else{
        echo "Wrong Name";
        return false;
        }
    }

public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
    }


public function setMobile($mobile){
    $mobilelen=strlen($mobile);
    if($mobilelen==10){
        $this->mobile=$mobile;
        return true;
    }else{
        echo "Wrong Mobile";
        return false;
        }
    }

public function getMobile(){
    return $this->mobile;
    }

public function save(){
$db=new DBManager();
$con=$db->getConnection();
$sql="insert into customer values('".$this->name."','".$this->mobile."')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);
}
}

Class DBManager{
    private $hostname='localhost';
    private $dbuser='root';
    private $dbpass='123';
    private $dbname='sem3';

public function getConnection(){
    return mysqli_connect($this->hostname,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass,$this->dbname);
}
}
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $x=new customer();
    $nameValidity=$x->setName($name);
    $mobileValidity=$x->setMobile($mobile);
    if($nameValidity && $mobileValidity)
        $x->save();

}

?>
```

Comment: your properties in the `customer` class should not be private. try `public`

Comment: How many fields do you have in your table customer.

Answer (score 1):

If there are more than 2 columns in customer table,
Add **Column Names** in your query.

```
$sql="insert into customer (column1,column2) values('".$this->name."','".$this->mobile."')";
```

**Example Query.**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
```

**OR**

Add null for remaining fields. Suppose you have 3 columns.

- id
- name
- mobile

  $sql="insert into customer values(NULL,'".$this->name."','".$this->mobile."')";

**NOTE:** Fields are in the same order and same number as the MySQL table fields.

Comment: if OP  has only 2 columns, there is no need to specify the columns. maybe confirm from OP first?

Comment: In this question mysqli procedural is used. Try to run the query without column names you get this error. 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871331/php-mysql-insert-into-without-using-column-names-but-with-autoincrement-field

Comment: Customer table have more than 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your query to insert should work provided the `customer` table only has two columns. The reason nothing gets saved is because your properties in the `customer` class are private. Make them public

Change

```
private $name;
private $mobile;
```

To

```
public $name;
public $mobile;
```

Also FYI your insert query is subject to SQL injection attacks. Use prepared statements.
Have a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) for more information